# confused by C++ logical OR (||) operator

Tags: c++

Suppose I have two expressions left/right of `||` operator. I find if left expression is true, the right operator will never be called. For example, in my below code, when `getRand` returns true, I found `Foo` will never be called. I tested on XCode on Mac OSX, and wondering if it is a reliable feature of C++ we could rely on -- if left part of || is true, right part will never be called, or it is a special feature just for specific platform (e.g. OSX with XCode)? Post my code below, thanks.

```
bool Foo()
{
    std::cout << "I am called!\n";
    return false;
}

bool getRand()
{
    int random_variable = std::rand();
    std::cout << random_variable << '\n';

    return random_variable % 2 == 1;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    if (getRand() || Foo())
    {
        std::cout<<"Hello World \n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: `wondering if it is a reliable feature of C++ we could rely on` Yes, it is.

Comment: && also have short circuit evaluation, if first argument is false

Comment: Short circuit evaluation is a reliable feature _most of the time_. It won't work if the used type has an overloaded && operator. Primitive types like `bool` are safe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is a guaranteed feature called [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Likewise, an expression  `false  &&  expression`  will never evaluate the right expression.

Answer (score 8):

> wondering if it is a reliable feature of C++ we could rely on -- if left part of || is true, right part will never be called?

Yes, for builtin operator.

From the standard, $5.15/1 Logical OR operator [expr.log.or] (bold by me)

> The || operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both
>   contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). It returns true if either
>   of its operands is true, and false otherwise. Unlike |, || guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; moreover, **the second operand is not
>   evaluated if the first operand evaluates to true**.

And note that the overload of `operator||` will lose this special property.

[Logical operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) (bold by me)

> Builtin operators && and || perform short-circuit evaluation (do not
>   evaluate the second operand if the result is known after evaluating
>   the first), but **overloaded operators behave like regular function
>   calls and always evaluate both operands**.

Answer (score 1):

Since its one choice or another there is no need for the second part to be evaluated, is not platform dependant is a language feature.